# Android - possible way to notify other i chatted using If statement passing in a user?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-activity, firebase

I wonder how to make an if statement in android studio like if you click the send button it will notify the one i contacted. would that possible in if else? i am creating chat app and i am using firebase as the storage of messages.do you think this would be possible?

```
if (view == button){
  //number of message
   numMessage++

}
else{

 "notification builder code?"
}
```

ugh i dunno if what would be the best possible way to notify the other i contacted . because if you set an intent in your send button it will just notify the emulator not the one you send a message. give an idea or any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try this, It should work, you might have to make some changes.

```
else{
Intent intent = new Intent();
     PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                                .setTicker("Ticker Title")
                                .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                                .setContentText("Notification content.")
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sad)
                               .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
                        noti.flags =Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
}
```

Comment: i tried that code many times in else but i got error in the PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0); it says that the .getActivity is not applicable. and the "this" marked red because of the error.